# What are some regions where land-living island animals have left fossil records within the sea, of the coast of the island?

Tags: geology, paleontology, fossils

What are some examples of fossil sites where land-living fossils end up in the sea, off the coast-line of an island?

[image: fossil site example]

Comment: define "island"  terrestrial fossil pop up in the western interior seaway, and germany has solnhofen which is a bay that has fossils of flying animals in it.

Comment: Terrestrial animals, whose fossils show up where there was water during their lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

Two sites in Australia, at opposite ends of the continent, that have such fossils are Cable Beach in [Broome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broome,_Western_Australia), Western Australia (in the north west of the Australia) and [Dinosaur Cove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_Cove), in Victoria (in the south east of Australia).

The fossils in Broome can only be seen at low tide and are of dinosaur footprints from the Cretaceous period, about 130 million years ago.

Dinosaur Cove has yielded bones that lead to the discovery of  [hypsilophodontid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypsilophodont)-like dinosaurs as [Leaellynasaura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaellynasaura) amicagraphica and [Atlascopcosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlascopcosaurus) loadsi, and a [Coelurosaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelurosauria), as well as fragments of what may be a [caenagnathid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caenagnathidae) (relatives of the [Oviraptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oviraptor))

Other information can be obtained from:

- [Broome dinosaurs](http://wkfl.asn.au/nature/dinosaurs.html)
- [Cretaceous dinosaur footprints uncovered on Western Australian
  beach](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2016/sep/07/dinosaur-footprints-from-cretaceous-period-uncovered-on-broomes-cable-beach)
- [Dinosaur Cove](http://dinosaurcoveaustralianfossilsite.weebly.com/types-of-fossils.html)

Comment: Looking for examples where the fossil-site was under water at the time, and where fossils from terrestrial animals were deposited, somehow, within the sea. About Broome, are you familiar with Carey and Maxlows' expansion tectonics? In expansion tectonics, during the early Cretaceous period 130 million years ago, the coast from Perth to coral bay was still attached to south-east Asia, and Broome was at the north-eastern edge of a rift that stretched from Exmouth to Darwin. Here is an image of that from Dr. James Maxlows' phD (2001), http://imgur.com/a/qlN2h

Comment: @Hermes -- You appear to be asking for a something that does not exist. This is a scientific site, while expanding earth is a non-scientific concept.

Comment: Guilt by association is also a non-scientific concept ;) The question is not related to global tectonics, rather to if there are known regions where terrestrial fossils have been deposited off-shore, by fluvial systems or faulting of the shore-line, or other ways. The reply to @Fred was off-topic, and directed to @ Fred.